# How to get Podman 3.1.2 running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Fresh installation with Raspberry Pi Imager of Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS (RPi 3/4/400) on a Raspberry Pi following standard tutorials:

```
cat /etc/os-release
export VERSION_ID=20.04
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable.list"
sudo wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:kubic:libcontainers:stable/xUbuntu_${VERSION_ID}/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt -y install podman
sudo podman -v
-> podman version 3.1.2

sudo podman run -dit nginx  # selected docker.io from repository
-> Error:  OCI runtime error: cannot find memory controller for the current process

sudo podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                              COMMAND               CREATED             STATUS   PORTS   NAMES
4a2dce0a3807  docker.io/library/nginx:latest     nginx -g daemon o...  46 seconds ago      Created          suspicious_williams
```

It creates an image but is not able to start the container. Any idea what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
sudo nano /root/firmware/cmdline.txt
this is is the ubuntu cmdline location.
Insert
cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_enable=cpu
right before
elevator=deadline
store and close (ctrl X and cr cr)
then
sudo reboot.
See also:
https://www.blogging-it.com/raspbian-warnung-kernel-lacks-cgroups-or-memory-controller-not-available-not-starting-cgroups/raspberry-pi/betriebssysteme-und-software.html

Comment: Thx for the link. It fits to the issue, I have opened. See https://github.com/containers/crun/pull/701